Why hot refers to being closer and cold refers to moving away in the hotter/colder game?
My question is about usage of hotter and colder in the children's game namely, "hotter/colder" or "hot and cold" game. Here is the description of the game:

It is a hiding game where one player gives clues to help another
player find a hidden object:  One player chooses an object to hide,
and the other player looks for it. The player hiding the object gives
clues to the seeker by saying "hotter" when the seeker is getting
closer, and "colder" when the seeker is moving away.

I'm wondering in this game why hot refers to being closer to the object and cold refers to moving away from it. Particularly, I'm curious to see if this usage is related to some meanings of the words hot and cold?

There's a Wikipedia article on the game and variations - it says that one 19th century variation was called "Hot Boiled Beans And Butter" so it may have a connection there. It's not really surprising to call out hot and cold - it's far enough from "near/far" to make it more interesting but close enough that it's clear what is meant. Wikipedia also links to a Portuguese version with quente/frio (warm/cold) so it's not just an English thing.

In many cultures, warmth is 'better' than cold if comfort is the context.

In the game, getting hotter means getting closer to the thing in question, and getting colder means you're moving away from it. If you think of the object as a fire,  you would find the fire by feeling warmth, and the closer you got to the fire, the warmer you would feel. There are many location where you would be cold but only one location where you would feel the heat of the fire.

"The hot and cold in hide-and-seek or guessing games (19c.) are from hunting (1640s), with notion of tracking a scent." - Says the OED without offering a lick of proof; https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=hot

@StuartF - Hot Boiled Beans (Circa 1850s; https://books.google.ch/books?redir_esc=y&hl=de&id=IkECAAAAQAAJ&q=beans#v=snippet&q=beans&f=false). Again, it's not made clear why hot = closer.

Extending @barbecue's point, we don't have "cold fires". Heat emanates circularly from a single point (I'm ignoring verticality here as that's not part of the general seeking game and heat convection is a very different thing), which is identical to your proximity to the thing you're looking for, i.e. it's based on your distance to the source (heat, or the thing you're looking for). You couldn't invert cold/hot and make it make sense on a temperature scale, so the analogy would break if applied to the searching game.

@flater you said what I was trying to say.

Hot and Cold was already a measure of closeness in Hunting Terminology
Another answer already said this is probably a tracking thing, but not why this terminology exists. The first written example I can find of hot used in tracking was 1595 in a scene describing the hunting of a deer:

By reason of his lazinesse and toile, the scent is very strong and hote, and easily entreth the noses of the dogges which maruellously incourageth them to his death.
~ G. Markham, Gentlemans Academie f. 37

In Middle English, Hote meant anything "intense" not just a measure of heat; so, in the late 1500s a strong scent was described as a "hot scent" by this and many following authors right up until this game was invented.

1650: J. Milton, Tenure of Kings
1709: Shaftesbury, Moralists
1750: J. S. Gardiner, Art & Pleasures of Hare-hunting
1875: W. S. Hayward, Love against World

(source)
By the 1640's you also start to see the use of the term "cold scent" establishing that when tracking an animal, the scent is either hot for good and therefore close or cold for bad and therefore far away.
This is probably enough to answer the question on its own; however, it is worth mentioning  that around the early 1800s, the terminology of a "hot trail" and "cold trail" also emerged as opposed to just a scent.  By this point in time, hot no long meant intense in a broad sense of the word, but more precisely was used to just refer to heat. So,the whole logic and terminology behind the expression started to shift and new rationalizations formed because of it.
Ashes or animal droppings that are still warm indicate that the person or animal that you are tracking is still near because they have not had time to cool down yet whereas cold signs indicate that they were left behind a while ago meaning that the thing you are tracking is probably far away by now.  However, as many tracking manuals point out such as The Art of Tracking by Louis-Liebenberg, this is only one of many freshness indicators.  Depending on what you are tracking, there may be many different signs of freshness such as if droppings wet or dry, if the tracks indicate that the animal was in a resting or motile mood, if the wind has eroded compression in the grass, etc.  In modern English, all of these ideas collectively represent a single concept that a trail is either hot or cold. So, in modern English, hot and cold are descriptors of the entire trace of an animal, and not just the intensity of its scent.
It was during this transitional period that Hot and Cold was added to this children's game making it impossible to determine which exact interpretation the words would have represented, but either way, it had to do with hunting terminology that would have already been well established at that point in time.
Other possible explanations exist like if you imagine the thing you are seeking is a fire or other hot thing, heat would radiate outward to let you know how close you are too it.  But the use of a proximal heat source as a measure of closeness was not already an established norm of the English language whereas the hotness of a trail was which leads me to believe it was most likely a hunting reference.

This answer is very plausible and makes great intuitive sense!  But that's not always reliable when it comes to etymology, unfortunately…  Is there any evidence for it?

@gidds: The OED tentatively supports this, though far from conclusively. For both hot and cold, it groups the “hide and seek” sense with the hunting sense, and the dates are line up suitably (the “hide and seek” senses develop in the 19th century, after the hunting senses were well-established).  On the other hand, they don’t state a connection explicitly, and there’s no clear “smoking gun” in the early citations.  So this suggests that professional lexicographers find a connection plausible, at least.

@gidds I've expanded my answer with dates and citations as well as a possible second explanation tying it to an alternate meaning of the word "hote" in Middle English, but every angle I approach it from ultimately points back to it being a hunting thing.

@WendyG I think you are missing my point.  Hot already meant that something you are hunting is close by hundreds of years before the game was invented.  It can be found in book after book going back in time.  So, it was already a well established part of the English language in the late 1800s. Why it means something is close by, and its cultural significance has transitioned over time, so saying how exactly its meaning was originally meant in the game is questionable, but not that hot already meant close.

@WendyG I've updated my language to be less absolute, but since folk games like this do not have any primary documentation explaining anything as specifically as you seem to be looking for, the best one can do is look at existing examples of Hot and Cold already being a casual measure of closeness in the language and culture of the day.  Even if you found an old written explanation, there is no way of knowing how long after the invention of the game the explanation comes from to know if it it actually reflects the original logic.

M+W sense 4b for hot gives this definition:

close to something sought
hot on the trail

In the OP's example, hotter is used in this sense, and colder is for the reverse.
hot
